# OpenGL context creation with ARB fails

Tags: c, winapi, opengl

I am trying to create an OpenGL context with the ARB extention. I read lots of documentations, posts and [the khronos wiki about that](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)). But i can't make the final context current, as you see in the code, the second wglMakeCurrent() call is commented out, which means that the context that is acctualy used is the first one created, without the extention. If I uncomment that, the window doesn't displays.

I did some error testing with the ARB functions, it seems that the problem comes from the attribute list or the wglChoosePixelFormatARB() call.

The code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <glew.h>

#include <GL\wglext.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);
unsigned int CreateShaderProgram(char* VertexSource, char* FragmentSource);

int main(void){
    WNDCLASSEX wcx = {};
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcx.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wcx.lpszClassName = L"Win32Class";
    RegisterClassEx(&wcx);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_LAYERED, wcx.lpszClassName, L"Title",
        WS_POPUP, 400, 300, 800, 400, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    DWM_BLURBEHIND blur = {};
    blur.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE | DWM_BB_BLURREGION;
    blur.fEnable = 1;
    blur.hRgnBlur = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, -1, -1);
    DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd, &blur);

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), 255, LWA_COLORKEY);

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {};
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 24;
    pfd.cStencilBits = 8;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    HDC DeviceContext = GetDC(hWnd);
    int PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(DeviceContext, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(DeviceContext, PixelFormat, &pfd);
    HGLRC RenderingContext = wglCreateContext(DeviceContext);
    wglMakeCurrent(DeviceContext, RenderingContext);

    glewInit();

    int Attributes[] = {
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        0,
    };

    PFNWGLCHOOSEPIXELFORMATARBPROC wglChoosePixelFormatARB =
        wglGetProcAddress("wglChoosePixelFormatARB");
    PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB =
        (PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC)
        wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");

    wglChoosePixelFormatARB(DeviceContext, Attributes, NULL, 1, &PixelFormat,
        NULL);
    SetPixelFormat(DeviceContext, PixelFormat, &pfd);
    RenderingContext = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(DeviceContext, NULL,
        Attributes);
    //wglMakeCurrent(DeviceContext, RenderingContext);

    char VertexShaderSource[] =
    "#version 440 core\n"
    "\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(){\n"
    "   gl_Position = position;\n"
    "}";

    char FragmentShaderSource[] =
    "#version 440 core\n"
    "\n"
    "layout(location = 0) out vec4 colour;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(){\n"
    "   colour = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);\n"
    "}";

    float Verticies[] = {
         0.0f,  0.5f, // top    : 0
         0.5f,  0.0f, // right  : 1
         0.0f, -0.5f, // bottom : 2
        -0.5f,  0.0f  // left   : 3
    };

    unsigned int Indices[] = {
        3, 0, 1, // top
        3, 2, 1  // bottom
    };

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    unsigned int VertexArray;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArray);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArray);

    unsigned int VertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * sizeof(float), Verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    unsigned int IndexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &IndexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned int), Indices,
        GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);

    unsigned int ShaderProgram = CreateShaderProgram(VertexShaderSource,
        FragmentShaderSource);
    glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 400);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, 1);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
        wglSwapLayerBuffers(DeviceContext, WGL_SWAP_MAIN_PLANE);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){
    switch(uMsg){
        case WM_NCHITTEST: return HTCAPTION;
        case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); return 0;
        default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wp, lp);
    }
}

unsigned int CreateShader(char* Source, unsigned int Type);

unsigned int CreateShaderProgram(char* VertexSource,
char* FragmentSource){
    unsigned int ShaderProgram = glCreateProgram(),
        VertexShader = CreateShader(VertexSource, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
        FragmentShader = CreateShader(FragmentSource, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, VertexShader);
    glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, FragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);
    glValidateProgram(ShaderProgram);
    return ShaderProgram;
}

unsigned int CreateShader(char* Source, unsigned int Type){
    unsigned int Shader = glCreateShader(Type);
    glShaderSource(Shader, 1, (const char* const*)&Source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(Shader);
    return Shader;
}
```

Note : The cast of the result of the second call to wglGetProcAdress() produces a warning if the -Wextra flag is set ( for the gcc compiler ). I don't know how to fix it.

Update : This still not works : "Choosing the final window pixel format failed." and "Creating the final rendering context failed." are printed (see the code) below. And the window does not displays.

The new code : (the big comment is the old code) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <glew.h>

#include <GL\wglext.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK FirstWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp,
    LPARAM lp);
LRESULT CALLBACK FinalWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp,
    LPARAM lp);
unsigned int CreateShaderProgram(char* VertexSource, char* FragmentSource);

int main(void){
    WNDCLASSEX FirstWindowClass = {};
    FirstWindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    FirstWindowClass.style = CS_OWNDC;
    FirstWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = FirstWindowProcedure;
    FirstWindowClass.lpszClassName = L"FirstWindowClass";
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&FirstWindowClass))
        puts("Registration of the first window class failed.\n");

    HWND FirstWindow = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
        FirstWindowClass.lpszClassName, L"FirstWindow", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 10, 10,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(FirstWindow == NULL)
        puts("Creation of the first window failed.\n");

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor = {};
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.nVersion = 1;
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.cColorBits = 32;
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.cDepthBits = 24;
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.cStencilBits = 8;
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    HDC FirstWindowDeviceContext = GetDC(FirstWindow);
    if(FirstWindowDeviceContext == NULL)
        puts("First window device context retrieving failed.\n");

    int FirstWindowPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(FirstWindowDeviceContext,
        &FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor);
    if(FirstWindowPixelFormat == 0)
        puts("Choosing the first pixel format failed.\n");

    if(SetPixelFormat(FirstWindowDeviceContext, FirstWindowPixelFormat,
    &FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor) == FALSE)
        puts("Setting the first pixel format failed.\n");

    HGLRC FirstWindowRenderingContext =
        wglCreateContext(FirstWindowDeviceContext);
    if(FirstWindowRenderingContext == NULL)
        puts("Creating the first rendering context failed.\n");

    if(wglMakeCurrent(FirstWindowDeviceContext, FirstWindowRenderingContext) ==
    FALSE)
        puts("Making the first context current failed.\n");

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        puts("Initialisation of GLEW failed.\n");

    WNDCLASSEX FinalWindowClass = {};
    FinalWindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    FinalWindowClass.style = CS_OWNDC;
    FinalWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = FinalWindowProcedure;
    FinalWindowClass.lpszClassName = L"FinalWindowClass";
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&FinalWindowClass))
        puts("Registration of the final window class failed\n");

    HWND FinalWindow = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
        FinalWindowClass.lpszClassName, L"FinalWindow", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 10, 10,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(FinalWindow == NULL)
        puts("Creation of the final window failed.\n");

    PFNWGLCHOOSEPIXELFORMATARBPROC wglChoosePixelFormatARB =
        wglGetProcAddress("wglChoosePixelFormatARB");
    if(wglChoosePixelFormatARB == NULL)
        puts("Getting the wglChoosePixelFormatARB function pointer failed.\n");

    PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB =
        (PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC)
        wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");
    if(wglCreateContextAttribsARB == NULL)
        puts("Getting the wglCreateContextAttribsARB function pointer"
            "failed.\n");

    int FinalWindowContextAttributes[] = {
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        0,
    };

    HDC FinalWindowDeviceContext = GetDC(FinalWindow);
    if(FinalWindowDeviceContext == NULL)
        puts("Retrieving the final window device cotext failed.\n");

    int FinalWindowPixelFormat;
    if(FALSE == wglChoosePixelFormatARB(FinalWindowDeviceContext,
    FinalWindowContextAttributes, NULL, 1, &FinalWindowPixelFormat, NULL))
        puts("Choosing the final window pixel format failed.\n");

    HGLRC FinalWindowRenderingContext =
        wglCreateContextAttribsARB(FinalWindowDeviceContext, NULL,
        FinalWindowContextAttributes);
    if(FinalWindowRenderingContext == NULL)
        puts("Creating the final rendering context failed.\n");

    if(FALSE == wglMakeCurrent(FinalWindowDeviceContext,
    FinalWindowRenderingContext))
        puts("Making the final context current failed.\n");

    DWM_BLURBEHIND blur = {};
    blur.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE | DWM_BB_BLURREGION;
    blur.fEnable = 1;
    blur.hRgnBlur = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, -1, -1);
    DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(FinalWindow, &blur);

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(FinalWindow, RGB(0, 0, 0), 255, LWA_COLORKEY);

    // -----   -----   ----- //

    /*WNDCLASSEX wcx = {};
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcx.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wcx.lpszClassName = L"Win32Class";
    RegisterClassEx(&wcx);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_LAYERED, wcx.lpszClassName, L"Title",
        WS_POPUP, 400, 300, 800, 400, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    DWM_BLURBEHIND blur = {};
    blur.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE | DWM_BB_BLURREGION;
    blur.fEnable = 1;
    blur.hRgnBlur = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, -1, -1);
    DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd, &blur);

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), 255, LWA_COLORKEY);

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {};
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 24;
    pfd.cStencilBits = 8;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    HDC DeviceContext = GetDC(hWnd);
    int PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(DeviceContext, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(DeviceContext, PixelFormat, &pfd);
    HGLRC RenderingContext = wglCreateContext(DeviceContext);
    wglMakeCurrent(DeviceContext, RenderingContext);

    glewInit();

    int Attributes[] = {
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        0,
    };

    PFNWGLCHOOSEPIXELFORMATARBPROC wglChoosePixelFormatARB =
        wglGetProcAddress("wglChoosePixelFormatARB");
    PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB =
        (PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC)
        wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");

    wglChoosePixelFormatARB(DeviceContext, Attributes, NULL, 1, &PixelFormat,
        NULL);
    RenderingContext = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(DeviceContext, NULL,
        Attributes);
    wglMakeCurrent(DeviceContext, RenderingContext);*/

    char VertexShaderSource[] =
    "#version 440 core\n"
    "\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(){\n"
    "   gl_Position = position;\n"
    "}";

    char FragmentShaderSource[] =
    "#version 440 core\n"
    "\n"
    "layout(location = 0) out vec4 colour;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(){\n"
    "   colour = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);\n"
    "}";

    float Verticies[] = {
         0.0f,  0.5f, // top    : 0
         0.5f,  0.0f, // right  : 1
         0.0f, -0.5f, // bottom : 2
        -0.5f,  0.0f  // left   : 3
    };

    unsigned int Indices[] = {
        3, 0, 1, // top
        3, 2, 1  // bottom
    };

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    unsigned int VertexArray;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArray);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArray);

    unsigned int VertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * sizeof(float), Verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    unsigned int IndexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &IndexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned int), Indices,
        GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);

    unsigned int ShaderProgram = CreateShaderProgram(VertexShaderSource,
        FragmentShaderSource);
    glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 400);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    ShowWindow(FinalWindow, 1);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
        wglSwapLayerBuffers(FinalWindowDeviceContext, WGL_SWAP_MAIN_PLANE);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK FirstWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wp, lp);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK FinalWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){
    switch(uMsg){
        case WM_NCHITTEST: return HTCAPTION;
        case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); return 0;
        default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wp, lp);
    }
}

unsigned int CreateShader(char* Source, unsigned int Type);

unsigned int CreateShaderProgram(char* VertexSource,
char* FragmentSource){
    unsigned int ShaderProgram = glCreateProgram(),
        VertexShader = CreateShader(VertexSource, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
        FragmentShader = CreateShader(FragmentSource, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, VertexShader);
    glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, FragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);
    glValidateProgram(ShaderProgram);
    return ShaderProgram;
}

unsigned int CreateShader(char* Source, unsigned int Type){
    unsigned int Shader = glCreateShader(Type);
    glShaderSource(Shader, 1, (const char* const*)&Source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(Shader);
    return Shader;
}
```

Comment: I Updated the question with the new code, see "Update :"

Comment: Note : When i remove the WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB and WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB flags, nothing is displayed in the console but there is no window and the program runs for a while an then stops.

Answer (score 3):

> SetPixelFormat(DeviceContext, PixelFormat, &pfd);

You can't do `SetPixelFormat()` twice for the same window - this is described in WinAPI documentation and elaborated in every article describing usage of `wglChoosePixelFormatARB`/`wglCreateContextAttribsARB` on Windows platform that I've seen:

> Once a window's pixel format is set, it cannot be changed.

The only way is creating a temporary OpenGL context on temporary window and then making an OpenGL context for a final window.

Add verbose checks to your code to see where it fails - don't ignore NULL checks and BOOL results of WinAPI functions.

Comment: We can't change the pixel format, I forgot it, but I think we can have two contexts for the same window (we just have to have only one current), it that true ? Could you give an exemple for the ARB part ? It's because I want to avoid ceating 2 windows, it's less efficient.

Comment: Well, creating multiple rendering context might work (don't know side effects - doesn't crash in my test). Note that `wglChoosePixelFormatARB` and `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` functions accept different list of Attributes, while in your sample uses the common list, which might cause problems.

Comment: @linternetsansfil: Efficiency is *irrelevant* in initialization code. The whole point of calling `wglChoosePixelFormatARB` is that it can get you different pixel formats compared to unextended WGL. Therefore, you may very well *need* to use a different pixel format, so you need to create a new window. So just recreate the window; it's standard for dealing with WGL.

Comment: I will of course destroy every thing i don't need (including the fake context), this was just a test. what do you mean by "Note that wglChoosePixelFormatARB and wglCreateContextAttribsARB functions accept different list of Attributes, while in your sample uses the common list, which might cause problems." ?

Comment: @NicolBolas The khronos wiki link I mentioned in the question does not provides an exemple for ARB, and I found none, do you have any link ?

Comment: The main reason i want ARB is to select the OpenGL version, pfd (RGBA 24 depth 8 stencil) is perfect in terms of pixel format for me

Comment: Will i need to reset glew after creating the second context ?

Comment: I've done some tests, I can create 1000 classes in a negligible time and 1000 windows in ~5 seconds so it won't be a problem : 10 classes created in 0.000000 seconds 10 windows created in 0.062000 seconds 100 classes created in 0.000000 seconds 100 windows created in 0.442000 seconds 1000 classes created in 0.016000 seconds 1000 windows created in 5.016000 seconds 10 classes created in 0.000000 seconds 10 windows created in 0.064000 seconds 100 classes created in 0.000000 seconds 100 windows created in 0.328000 seconds 1000 classes created in 0.016000 seconds 1000 windows created in 5.0660 sec